# TaskFactory.StartNew<TResult> Method (Func<Object, TResult>, Object)

Tags: c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I was giving a read about creating a continuation for multiple antecedents in MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288(v=vs.110).aspx and am having a hard time understanding the code, one of their examples used. I am pasting the code below.

```
for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++) {
    int baseValue = ctr;
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew( (b) =>
      {
        int i = (int) b;
        return i * i;
      },
      baseValue));
}
```

When I read about `StartNew` overload, the [MSDN states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321394.aspx):

```
public Task<TResult> StartNew<TResult>(
  Func<object, TResult> function,
  object state
)
```

**Parameters**

*function*

Type: `System.Func<Object, TResult>`
A function delegate that returns the future result to be available through the `Task<TResult>`.

*state*

Type: `System.Object`
An object containing data to be used by the function delegate.

To be specific, in their example, I am not understanding the usage of `baseValue`, when `b` is passed as an `Object` to the function.

Comment: `baseValue` is a state object that gets passed to the delegate provided to `StartNew`. In the example `baseValue` will take the value of `ctr` as the loop executes. [On another note stay away from `StartNew`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)

Comment: What b is for ?

Comment: b is the parameter being passed to the lamda, it's roughly equivalent to `void SomeFunc(int b)`.

Comment: Pardon my silly questions, how does baseValue fit in the example.

Comment: To actually pass an argument to the lamda `StartNew` needs to know about it: so you pass whatever you argument you want to go to the lamda into `StartNew` When the lamda executes `b` will take the value that was passed in with `baseValue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is `Func<object, TResult>`? It is a type of a delegate, which accepts `object` and returns `TResult`: `TResult MethodName(object b)`.

Here in code sample the method is being constructed with inline lambda, which accepts `object b` and returns `int` (you can see the list of tasks which will return `int` - `List<Task<int>> tasks`):

```
private int Square(object b)
{
    int i = (int) b;
    return i * i;
}
```

Now you need to **call** this method, so you're passing the second parameter, `baseValue`. So for each number from `1` to `10` you get the square of it: `1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25 + 36 + 49 + 64 + 81 + 100`, and after that you sum them up and get `385`.

So, whole code can be read as:

```
for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
{
    resultList.Add(Square(ctr));
}
```

but whole computations will occur inside the task.
This can be rewritten as:

```
for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++)
{
    // get a local copy of ctr
    var baseValue = ctr;
    // create a task which will get the square
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => baseValue * baseValue));
    // or with a method introduction
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => Square(baseValue)));
}
```

but in this case you'll get a closures, so the delegate inside `Task` will be re-created each time comparing with an initial variant without closures (thanks for @CoryNelson).

Note that initial code is a sample, and should not be used as a pattern to reproduce in production code: it blocks the current execution with `.Result` (which is ok only as `main` method couldn't be `async`) and it uses `StartNew`, which [can behave unexpectedly](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html).

Some useful links:

- [The Beauty of Closures](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter5/Closures.aspx)
- [C# Closures Explained](http://www.codethinked.com/c-closures-explained)
- [`Func<T, TResult>` delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx)
- [Lambda Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) (C# Programming Guide)
- [Lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/lambda-expressions) (from learn.microsoft.com)

Comment: I'd add that the reason you'd use that overload versus a capturing lambda is that capturing allocates a new delegate every time, while a non-capturing one will only be allocated once.

Comment: @CoryNelson Thanks, added that too.

Comment: Seems like lambda concept is not clear in my mind. 
I was hoping to see,
`for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 10; ctr++) {
    object b = object(ctr);
    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew( (b) =>
      {
        int i = (int) b;
        return i * i;
      });
}`

Comment: Lambda is a method **definition**. After you define method, you need to **call** it, with a parameter, in your case it is `baseValue`. In your code you do not provide a parameter value, so code wouldn't compile.

Comment: My code example in the comments wouldn't Compile You are correct, I just wanted to share what was running into my mind. 
So what is b in the left hand of lambda operator, I thought that is the input, delegate method is requiring for to run, but somebody got to set the value of b and that was via baseValue.
Who call this method

Comment: As have been already said, lambda is a **method declaration**, `b` is a **parameter** in a method declaration, and `baseValue` is a **value** for the parameter. `Task` itself is taking care about the calling the lambda method with a given parameter.

Comment: To be clear, `Func<...>` is not a generic method, it's a *type* and an instance of that type is a delegate.